# How do you get the id from the fabricjs canvas object?

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

How do I get the id element from a fabricjs canvas object? I understand I pass in an ID into the constructor when I make a new one, but after it has been constructed. How do I get the id from the canvas object I just created?

It seems like such a simple thing, but yet I can't find it.

```
var newCanvas = new fabric.Canvas("myId");
var newCanvasId = newCanvas.id;    //doesn't work, undefined
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`new fabric.Canvas()` does not return a Canvas DOM Element but rather a FabricJS Canvas object with its own set of attributes and methods. If you want to access the actual canvas that FabricJS paints on, there's a [getElement()](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#getElement) method:

```
var newCanvas = new fabric.Canvas("myId");
var newCanvasId = newCanvas.getElement().id; // "myId"
```

Comment: this is exactly it!

Comment: how to select the canvas element with id?